# How do you delete all models in an Alloy Collection

Tags: appcelerator, backbone.js-collections, appcelerator-alloy

From within a controller function, how do you delete all the models in an Alloy Collection. The collection is using properties sync adapter. I think the backbone reset method is the way to go but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way for me was to run `destroy()` on every model. To do this quickly you can use underscore (build in) like this:

```
_.invoke(Alloy.Collections.library.toArray(), 'destroy');
```

or even extend the model.js

```
extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
            dump: function() {
                // get all models
                return this.models;
            },
            clear: function() {
                // remove/destroy all models
                _.invoke(this.toArray(), 'destroy');
            }
        });

        return Collection;
}
```

and run `Alloy.Collections.library.clear();`

Pro Tip: you can always search for things like `delete all models in backbone` and use most of the results right away since it is using backbone in the background.